# PHPExcel - how do I set a cell to contain time only (without date)

Tags: time, phpexcel

I need to put h:mm value to a cell, however I was able to either set it as text or set it as a time but containing the actual date (DateTime adds it and I cannot get rid of it).

```
    $dto = new DateTime("11:00");
    $dateVal = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($dto);

    $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cell)
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode('h:mm');

    $this->objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell, $dateVal);
```

The cell appears as 11:00 in Excel (while it is formatted as h:mm), but the cell value contains actual date (24/10/2019 11:00:00).

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: You would have to treat the column as plain text instead of as a date field. Internally Excel is going to store a complete date. You are asking it to only display a portion of the actual date. That will not change what is actually stored in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I've tried plain text, but it is a text type then and the time functions doesn't work.

Specifically, I need to compare this cell to a another time cell, like 8:00 and find out, what is greater (what time is later). Comparing 8:00 with text doesn't work, neither comparing 8:00 with a cell containing time&date. :-(